# How to animate (motion) according to google android design

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

Android Animation(Motion), On selecting an item from right drawer display item name on screen with animation.

1. open right nav bar           (done)
2. Click on item                (done)
3. Dismiss drawer               (done)
4. Displaying item name on screen (top left)  (done)

after step 2. I want a motion-animation to display name

Comment: provide useful codes or images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you can add animation libraries for text view..
[use this library](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView)